# Stl Files and Adding Bases

Tags: modeling, mesh, export

I am working on a project which uses a 3D printer to print parts of the moon, and was linked this add-on to start creating my own models, I have got to this stage[image]

but when i export the file as a stl from this point, the stl loads nothing.

Also is there a way to add a flat base to the model, so it sits smoothly when I print it

[Blend File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0J7WNqkpR3AeUc2SDFZbHdPOEk/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: 3D print objects can't have any holes in the mesh itself. Your current mesh doesn't have a bottom, so basicly there is no volume to print.

Comment: So how do I add a bottom, I have never used this software before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**How to add a flat base:**

First of all, you need to reposition your mesh so that it is horizontal. After that, select your mesh, press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>, click (don't move the mouse), and drag the new mesh down along the Z-axis. Now go into *Edit mode*, with <kbd>Tab</kbd>, select everything with <kbd>A</kbd>, press <kbd>S</kbd> to scale, <kbd>Z</kbd> (limit scaling to Z-axis) and <kbd>0</kbd>. Your mesh should be flat. Go into *Object mode*, select both your objects, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> to join objects, go into *Edit mode* again, select the outer edges of both surfaces with <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>RMB</kbd>, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd>, select `Bridge edge loops`, and you're basically done.
The result should look a bit like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, one last question, how do i reposition the mesh to horizontal?

Comment: Watch a few beginner tutorials, you will probably need more knowledge than only repositioning objects before you can try to achieve something in blender. Just google "blender beginner tutorial".