# How to fill base for 3d printing a topographic map

Tags: displacement, 3d-printing, height-map

I would like to 3d print a topographic map of the world. I’m starting from the following grayscale PNG.

[image]

I have previously played with Blender to render this shape using a grid mesh and the displace modifier. However just exporting the resulting mesh to obj/stl hasn’t worked with my slicing software.

I suspect the main problem is that the grid isn’t “filled” underneath -- how would I go about fixing that?

Comment: @susu Sure, I've edited to leave only one question

Comment: For similar questions already on this site, use the search box at the top. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/62384/how-can-i-make-a-closed-flat-base-for-an-object and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/32688/stl-files-and-adding-bases and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/192625/how-to-create-a-flat-base-to-a-photogrammetry-model-in-blender and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/170655/adding-thickness-to-3d-printed-topographic-map and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/41045/how-to-solidify-a-complex-2d-render-from-pix4d-for-3d-printing